# FTP File copy command in Juniper showing [error: file-fetch failed error: could not fetch local copy of file]?

Tags: juniper-junos

I Have two Juniper ACX 2200 Series Routers connected back to back and One Router running latest OS, But other is running Old OS,

I want to copy Latest OS from One Junos to another Junos Router,

I enabled FTP On both Routers

```
[edit system services ftp]
set rate-limit 2
set connection-limit 2
```

And Used The Command

```
ikar@hostname> file copy ftp://ikar:ikar123@172.22.36.113/var/tmp/jinstall-ppc-15.1X54-D36.2-domestic.tgz /var/tmp
```

And I got the Below Error

```
fetch: ftp://ikar:*@172.22.36.113/var/tmp/jinstall-ppc-15.1X54-D36.2-domestic.tgz: File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access)
error: file-fetch failed
error: could not fetch local copy of file
```

User : ikar has Super-user privilages.

Comment: Have you tried connecting using an ordinary ftp client rather than Junipers? It might give you more information in regards to access perhaps. I know it's a silly question, but have you double checked that the file is actually present on the source? Alternatively, try using SCP if you have SSH setup using scp://user@hostname/path/filename

Comment: @SleepyMan It works with external ftp client, and file exists in the /var/tmp directoy, I asked this question because in case if routers lost connectivity to external ftp clent , i should be able transfer images via another router,

Comment: @SleepyMan thanks for suggesting scp, i will try with it.

Comment: @SleepyMan And also I don't happen to find specific documents where copying junos OS from one router to another is mentioned . If you have one please mention it.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are having problems in getting the URL right, jump into the FreeBSD shell (using "start shell") and do the ftp from there:

```
user@router> start shell
% ftp 192.168.254.254
Connected to 192.168.254.254.
220 router FTP server (Version 6.00LS) ready.
Name (192.168.254.254:user): user
331 Password required for user.
Password:
230 User user logged in.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> bin
200 Type set to I.
ftp> get <file>
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
ikar@hostname> file copy ftp://ikar@172.22.36.113/var/tmp/jinstall-ppc-15.1X54-D36.2-domestic.tgz /var/tmp
```

You'll be prompted for password, put in the password and you should be good to go

(Source: http://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos15.1/topics/reference/command-summary/file-copy.html#jd0e160)

Comment: I have already tried that one, it will give the same error, by the way both methods are same.